# How to easily implement member functions as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to develop a container which can sort its element with its attribute access member functions, such as Name(). I want to use it as the following

```
SortedVector<T, &T::Name> v;
T t;
v.Add(t);
v.FindElementWithName("AName");
```

How to declare the template class? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "template class" or "class template"? Hmmm...

Comment: Do you want that exact syntax?  Or would something equivalent do?

Comment: Seems like the trickery that's going to be required won't be worth the few extra lines a comparator for `std::map` would take.  I suppose if it's a frequent requirement though it might be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no declaration that allows the simple usage that you envision unless you *allow only one function result type*.

With that restriction you can do e.g.

```
template< class Item, std::string (Item::*)() const >
class SortedVector;
```

But more generally (not supporting the simple notation) you can do

```
template< class Item, class Result, Result (Item::*)() const >
class SortedVector;
```

The main problem is anyway how to leverage the standard library's classes.

I think I would use a `std::vector` for the storage and a `std::map` for the sorting, maybe.

Comment: I was trying to write more generic class template, but at the same time didn't want to pass `ReturnType` and `Args...`. Maybe few typedefs definitions in `T` could help, or some trait class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code which does something pretty similar to what you want: provides sorting based on a "keygetter" from a single object rather than a comparator on two objects.  A C++11x version using lambdas ought to be considerably cleaner (this is adapted from some old gcc 4.4 code).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <
  typename T,
  typename K
> struct sort_by_key_comparator {

  sort_by_key_comparator(boost::function<K(const T&)> keygetter)
    :_keygetter(keygetter){}

  bool operator()(const T& a,const T& b) {
    return (_keygetter(a)<_keygetter(b));
  }

  boost::function<K(T)> _keygetter;
};

// Sort an iterator range based on comparison of
// keys of type K retrieved from ojects of type T
template <
  typename IT,
  typename T,
  typename K
> void sort_by_key(
  IT first,
  IT last,
  boost::function<K(const T&)> keygetter
) {
  sort_by_key_comparator<T,K> cmp(keygetter);
  std::sort(first,last,cmp);
}

class data {

public:

  data(int id,const std::string& txt)
    :_id(id),_txt(txt){}

  int get_id() const {return _id;}

  const std::string& get_txt() const {return _txt;}

private:
  int _id;
  std::string _txt;
};

int main(int,char**) {

  std::vector<data> v;
  v.push_back(data(0,"d"));
  v.push_back(data(3,"c"));
  v.push_back(data(1,"b"));
  v.push_back(data(2,"a"));

  boost::function<int(const data&)> idkey=
    boost::bind(&data::get_id,_1);

  sort_by_key(v.begin(),v.end(),idkey);

  for (size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i) 
    std::cout << v[i].get_id() << ", " << v[i].get_txt() << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  boost::function<std::string(const data&)> txtkey=
    boost::bind(&data::get_txt,_1);

  sort_by_key(v.begin(),v.end(),txtkey);

  for (size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i)
    std::cout << v[i].get_id() << ", " << v[i].get_txt() << std::endl;
}
```

Interestingly, [Python's sorting](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions) uses this "keygetter" style, while C++'s STL/std library has of course been [based on two-object comparators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/).  Scala helpfully [provides both styles](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) (via `sortBy` and `sortWith`).